# PayPal - changing recurrent payment to 1-time payment

Tags: paypal

How do I change a recurring payment to a one-time payment in PayPal?

Comment: Sorry, you'll [have to](http://superuser.com/faq) take this question to some PayPal support forum. (I doubt [Where can I ask questions that aren’t Super User questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41570/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-super-user-questions) helps, but who knows. Success!)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I have a lot of experience with this, because, in a moment of insanity, my company put a number of recurring transactions in PayPal. A year later, the cost changed, and we went to see if we could update the recurrent transactions.

The answer is simple: You can't.

The customer put in the recurring transaction on their credit card. Paypal does not expose that information to their business partners, and they don't allow their business partners to change the recurring payments, or schedule payments that are in any way different from what the customer signed up for.

The only way to change it is to cancel the transaction, and have the customer go in and put in a new transaction.